# Laravel 5 Form upload direct to S3 Bucket not working

Tags: php, forms, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I've been playing with Laravel 5 for about a week now and loving it, but I can't for the life of me get this to work.
I have a simple page that uploads an image to my S3 bucket.

```
{!! Form::open(['post' => '/dash/profile/avatar/', 'files' => true]) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::file('avatar') !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Upload', ['class' => 'form-control button']) !!}
        </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The applicable route(s)

```
Route::get('/dash/profile/avatar', 'ProfileController@updateAvatar');

Route::post('/dash/profile/avatar/', 'ProfileController@uploadAvatar');
```

And my ProfileController method for the upload

```
public function uploadAvatar(Filesystem $filesystem, Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $filename = $request->file('avatar')->getFilename();
            $file = $request->file('avatar');
            $filesystem->put('test.jpg', $file);
            return redirect('dash/profile')->with(['flash_message' => 'Your Avatar has been successfully updated!']);
        } else {
            return redirect('auth/login');
        }
    }
```

All I get in my S3 bucket is a file called 'test.jpg' as expected, but it is only a few bytes, rather than the ~500KB image I'm attempting to upload.
Can anyone tell me why?
Thanks in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

you migth want to give this a try:

```
$filesystem->put('test.jpg', \File::get($file->getRealPath());
```

The second argument of `put` is what will be written into the file, so instead of the file object, make sure to pass the actual content.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Instead of `\File::get()` you can also use PHP's own `file_get_contents()` function in the second argument of `put`, so `$filesystem->put('test.jpg', file_get_contents('path/to/test.jpg'));`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem! It had nothing to do with Laravel. Changed the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to a large enough value (50M). Destroyed all php5-fpm sessions by doing `sudo pkill php5-fpm` and then started the php5-fpm service by doing `service php5-fpm start`. Then everything worked and the file was uploaded to `/tmp`.